# Creating an Array from UnsafeBufferPointer in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation

Usually people are asking for things to transform from Objective-C to Swift. I have to ask the other way round today.

Given the following line in Swift:

```
let values:[Float] = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: buffer.floatChannelData?[0], count:Int(buffer.frameLength)))
```

Compiles successfully and I get an array of float values. Since `floatChannelData` on `AVAudioPCMBuffer` is defined as `float * const` I was assuming that the returning array of values is copied from the address `floatChannelData[0]` points to.

How would I achieve the same behaviour in Objective-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on whether you want a C array of `float`s, or an `NSArray`.

(disclaimer: written in Chrome)

For a C array, we should be able to just copy the original values:

```
float *values = malloc(buffer.frameLength * sizeof(float)); // remember to free eventually
memcpy(values, buffer.floatChannelData[0], buffer.frameLength * sizeof(float));
```

For an `NSArray` we will have to wrap the `float`s in `NSNumber` objects:

```
NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray new];

for (AVAudioFrameCount i = 0; i < buffer.frameLength; i++) {
    [values addObject:@(buffer.floatChannelData[0][i])];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Compiler still not too happy `Illegal type 'float *'` used in a boxed expression.

Comment: My bad, misread your OP and didn't notice that `floatChannelData` was a `float **` rather than a `float *`. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: That's the solution! Thanks! Nice to know about the `AVAudioFrameCount` typedef as well.